# Configuring Hadoop 1.2.0 on windows

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, hadoop2

Can any one of you help me how to install hadoop on windows server with cygwin actually when ever I set `JAVA_HOME` variable in `hadoop-env.sh` file it always gives an error like `EOF command not found` and please also can any one of you tell me how to make cluster and import csv file in hadoop?

> $ bin/hadoop namenode -format
>   /home/My/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not                                                  found
>   /home/My/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not                                                  found
>   /home/My/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 31: unexpected EOF whi                                                 le looking for matching '"' /home/My/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 58: syntax error: unexpected end of file
>   Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

This is the above error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you tried to install hadoop in windows, you need to create `batch` file instead of .sh file, windows doesn't support the .sh files. create `hadoop-env.cmd` and try again.